# Code sharing among student groups and access permisions over Local area network, no command line

Tags: version-control, code-sharing

I need a smart code sharing tool that can be installed on windows machines.
It should enable a students club to do the following:

1. Enable **EASY** folder and file sharing over lan network, (can work without internet)
2. Manage access levels for individuals **AND GROUPS** (read, write, create, delete files)
3. Add folders to watch list then scan and update automatically

Optionally:
4. Code comparing
5. featured code editor integrated

Please dont point to me applications that only work via typing commands, students get scared ;)

Comment: Recently a friend of mine shared some stuff through [Dropbox Folder Sharing](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en), it uses LAN when possible as well. Only thing thats missing would be group access level I'm assuming.

Comment: thanks, ill give it a try. does it do file access levels?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used it so don't really know :P